# How to Authenticate user on Android using Rails Devise as backend?

Tags: android, ruby-on-rails, json, devise, jwt

I am using Rails 5 application as a backend for my Android app. On my rails, I am using Devise to authenticate users and I have implemented the JWT gem with rack-cors to pass token https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EF5Cm2jZHk0.

I am struggling with my Android app and I am not able to authenticate users. I am using Retrofit2 with Android and I have passed credentials with the header but I am getting the response code 401 (Not Authorized).

I am open for any kind of suggestions that can lead me to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, this appears to be a really old question, but will answer anyway, for the sake of someone who will come across the same issue, if a model has device installed on it,then we can access a particular object and have the method valid_password?
For example `user = User.find_by_email("doe@example.com")`, to find if the password is right, then we use `user.valid_password?("password")`, this will return `true` if it's the password for that user.